# Algebraic Proof of Equivalent Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone please explain why the two equations below are equivalent (if they are).

> $y = \sqrt[3]{6x\sqrt{1+x} - 4(1+x)^\frac{3}{2}}$
>
> $y = \sqrt[3]{2(1+x)^\frac{3}{2} - 6\sqrt{1+x}}$

where each are cube roots (if it's difficult to see). I've been working through some differential equations and I preformed integration by parts, but the book I'm working out of solved the problem differently and came up with a different result.

I've plugged in a few points in wolfram alpha and I believe they are the same, but my algebra isn't good enough to see how they are the same (or I'm looking over something completely obvious). Anyway, can someone show me algebraically why the two equations are equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignore the cube root - it's a red herring.

Factor out the $\sqrt{1+x}$:

$$6 x \sqrt{1+x} - 4 (1+x)^{3/2} = \sqrt{1+x} (6 x - 4 (1+x)) = 2 \sqrt{1+x} (x + 1 - 3)$$

The rest you should be able to do.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The two terms inside each cube root have a common factor of $(1+x)^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 2):

If you rewrite $-4$ as $2-6$, then $$\begin{align}6x\sqrt{1+x}-4(1+x)^{\frac32} &= 2(1+x)^{\frac32}+6x\sqrt{1+x}-6(1+x)^{\frac32}\\ &= 2(1+x)^{\frac32}+6x\sqrt{1+x}-6(1+x)\sqrt{1+x}\\ &= 2(1+x)^{\frac32}-6\sqrt{1+x}.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\sqrt[3]{6x\sqrt{1+x}-4(1+x)^{3/2}}=\sqrt[3]{2(1+x)^{3/2}-6\sqrt{1+x}}\stackrel{\text{raise to third power and a little algebra}}\iff$$

$$2\sqrt{1+x}\;\left[3x-2(1+x)\right]=2\sqrt{1+x}\;\left[1+x-3\right]\ldots$$